# Dynamic import() file in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to import markup file dynamically slice part of file and add result to variable and render result in my React app:

```
import('../changelog.md').then(...)
```

I trying to do it in `render()` method with all logic but I have problems. Where I need to import it (in class or outside) and how to get value of promise to paste it to variable?

Comment: `import()` isn't any different than any other promise in this regard. Call `setState` in `then`. Wherever possible, use synchronous import. It's unclear from the question why would it be dynamic, since import module is known.

Comment: assuming this is a real changelog, it isn't going to change while the app runs, because the app won't be silently live-updating itself. Parse the .md file to something JS can work with during your build step and bundle that in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    state = {html: null}

    componentDidMount() {
        import('../changelog.md').then(mod => {
            this.setState({html: mod.default})
        })
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.html ? <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:this.state.html}} /> : <p>Loading...</p>
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a `.md` loader and it returns HTML.

`import()` returns a Promise. So you'll have to wait for it to resolve before you can render it. Easiest way to do that is to do it in `componentDidMount` (React [recommends](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) you put all ajax request there and this is kind of similar) and then copy it into state to force a re-render when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `await` keyword within an `async` method.

```
async function render() {
    var markup = await import('../changelog.md');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Don't think you can make `render` async in React 16. Maybe when 17 comes out (see "react suspense")

Answer (score 0):

import your .md file at start like this.

```
import yourMDObject from '../changelog.md';
```

and then you can use `fetch()` like this

```
fetch(yourMDObject).then(obj =>obj.text()).then(..)
```

Comment: That's not a dynamic import.

Comment: What are you even fetching? Are you assuming `yourMDObject` is a URL? And it's stored in an `.md` file? That seems unusual.