# Change react component css based on props with css-modules

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have the following:

```js
className={`${this.props.match.params.id}.alert`}

/* desired output = `className="style_alert__3TLGs"` */
/* instead output = `className="style.alert"` */
```

If I hardcode the className (eg. `{style.alert}`), I get the desired output. It seems as though the result is a string and is not being handled by the css-module package (perhaps because it's rendered after?), how can I change this so the className is handled by css-module and bundled as I intend?

reference docs: [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Why do you send an id to the class ? `${this.props.match.params.id}.alert` will become something like `className="48.alert"`.

Comment: When you use string interpolation the result will be a string, this is not unexpected.  What is the value of `this.props.match.params.id`?

Comment: @ValentinDuboscq - Very simple, the id represents a css module, that I want to call on a reusable component, and the style changes depending on which id is in use. This is then handled by the css-modules package. Here is a very simple example: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Comment: @DrewReese the value in the example above is "style", I understand it's not unexpected but my question is how can I achieve the outcome I desire with a prop that may be different each time and have it handled by the css-modules package correctly?

Comment: Are you simply trying to dynamically assign a classname from some "styles" object, say, something like `className={styles[this.props.match.params.id].alert}`?

Comment: @DrewReese I think he wants to dynamically import different css modules based on the id. Maybe I don't quite understand but I don't think that's the right to do what you want to do.

Comment: @ValentinDuboscq Ah, yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Yep, @ValentinDuboscq got it! I'm trying to dynamically change the css based on the id. I'm just unsure of the best approach and looking for some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** Import all style modules you know you'll use

Create a map of your imported "style" objects to be keyed by the `id`s passed in the prop. Just need to ensure all "style" objects have all the same CSS properties, like "alert", and of course, use guard pattern on the object path to the `id` param so no "undefined of" accesses.

```
import styles1 from "....";
import styles2 from "....";
...

const stylesMap = {
  style1Id: styles1,
  style2Id: styles2,
  ...
};

...

className={stylesMap[this.props.match.params.id].alert}
```

Pros: front load all the CSS modules you need and likely a little easier to reason about and debug

Cons: Uses more resources

**Option 2:** Use dynamic imports

Create an async function to "fetch" the required CSS module and use a component lifecycle function or effect hook to update the style object reference.

```
const loadStyle = async (...params) => {
  try {
    const styleObject = await import(...path and module name from params);
    // setState or useState setter to set style object
  } catch {
    // set a fallback style object
  }
}
...

componentDidMount() {
  // check props.match.params.id
  // gather up other CSS module path details
  // trigger dynamic CSS module load
  loadStyle(... CSS module path detials);
}
**OR**
useEffect(() => {
  // check props.match.params.id
  // gather up other CSS module path details
  // trigger dynamic CSS module load
  loadStyle(... CSS module path detials);
}, [props.match.params.id, ...any other dependencies]);

...

className={stylesMap[<this.>state.styleObject].alert}
```

Pros: Smaller size/less resource use.

Cons: Possibly more latency when rendering as resources are not fetched ahead of time.

**Note:** Also all depends on your app usage, needs, and requirements. For example, if it is a bundled app (think cordova/phonegap, electron, etc) then it is more sensible to include all the resources you need.

Comment: Maybe using [dynamic import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335485/dynamic-import-file-in-js) is a best approach since you don't need to import all your files.

Comment: @ValentinDuboscq I included the idea to use dynamic imports, thanks. Feel free to point out any flaws/errors.